# Minimum Software and Hardware requirements for SharePoint 2013 developer Environment

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, system-requirements

I am a sharepoint developer and was looking for software & hardware requirements for setting up just the **developer** environment for SharePoint 2013, its only for testing and developing sharepoint solutions on my PC/laptop.

I looked into the Microsoft list of hardware & software requirements but they focus on setting up the whole SP2013 environment and i presume that it is not the same for developing solutions on my PC/laptop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The software and hardware requirements for SharePoint development are the same as the software and hardware requirements for Visual Studio 2012.  Microsoft says these are:

- 1.6 GHz or faster processor
- 1 GB of RAM (1.5 GB if running on a virtual machine)
- 10 GB (NTFS) of available hard disk space
- 5400 RPM hard drive
- DirectX 9-capable video card running at 1024 x 768 or higher display resolution
- Windows 7 SP1 or better

However, if you want decent performance, you should probably have, at a minimum:

- 3.0 Ghz or faster quad core processor
- 4 GB of RAM
- 7200 RPM Hard Drive (preferably an SSD)

This will satisfy VS requirements, as well as providing sufficient memory and horsepower to run SharePoint Server in a virtual machine.

**See Also**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timquin/archive/2013/01/22/setting-up-visual-studio-2012-for-sharepoint-2013-development-offline.aspx

Comment: Which Operating system would be sufficient to install it on my laptop?

Comment: The System Requirements for Visual Studio are here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility.  It says Windows 7 SP1 or better.